# What is the standard approach for setting up a Visual Studio 2010 solution for ASP.NET MVC 3 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently working on a ASP.NET MVC 3 project and I am setting up the solution file on VS2010.

I am not sure of what is the standard approach. I am using the following approach

1. Company.Dept.Data (contains the dbml file - Data Model)
2. Company.Dept.Business (Business logics)
3. Company.Dept.Web (contains ASP.NET MVC3 webapplication)

The first two are class libraries and the last one is MVC3 web application.
Anyother recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single "standard" approach. It all depends on your project and what problems you are trying to solve with the software. Your proposed structure of having 2 class libraries and 1 web project is one way to go for sure.

If you are going to do any kind of Dependency Injection using an Inversion of Control container, you might also want to consider having an "API" project for interfaces and an "Impl(ementation)" project for concrete classes that fulfill the interface contracts.

Answer (score 0):

To echo danludwig, there really is no standard. I prefer breaking up libraries and namespaces according to functionality. Company.Db is my library for interacting with the database, Company.Mail are my wrappers around the Postmark mail service, etc.

I then tend to group like libraries into single repositories. So the 'storage' repository in source control holds Company.Db, Company.Caching, Company.FileStorage, etc. I have another repository 'messaging' that holds Company.Mail and Company.SMS (for interacting with Twilio to send text messages). When I branch out with new apps or new services (maybe a WCF endpoint for mobile clients), I can just pull down the 'messaging' repository, and I have all my class libraries for communicating with the user.

An application then looks like

```
Company.Application.Webite 
     \Libraries\Messaging
          \Libraries\Messaging\Company.Mail
     \Libraries\Storage
          \Libraries\Messaging\Company.Db
          \Libraries\Messaging\Company.Caching
     \Libraries\Web
     ...
Company.Application.Wcf
     \Libraries\Messaging
     \Libraries\Storage
          \Libraries\Messaging\Company.Db
          \Libraries\Messaging\Company.Caching
     ...
```

This way, whether someone registers via the site, or via the mobile app, Company.Mail.MailServices.SendWelcomeEmail() sends the exact same welcome email, and there's no code duplication.

Whether this works for you, or even makes sense, who knows. I've also changed this scheme a hundred times, trying to find a layout that works with my development style/workflow. I wouldn't worry or stress too much about it, because whatever you pick, you're going to find things you like about it, and you'll find things you hate about it. I sometimes fall into the trap of spending more time trying to make everything "perfect", than to just code and change things I don't like.

Comment: I appreciate your input. Thank you!